# SwiftUI Conditional List - Unable to infer complex closure return type

Tags: swift, swiftui

I know questions involving this error have been asked before, but I have looked through them and none of them have helped me solve this particular issue.

I have a List, which depending on a certain condition, will have some items filtered out. Here it is:

```swift
List(tasks) { task in

    if (!self.toggleIsOn) || (!task.completed.status) {

        TaskRowView(task)

    }

}
```

Everything works fine, but when I add the conditional, it gives me this error:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

On the `List` line. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List expects a View returned for every item, using Group like that is a bit of a hack.

Better to move the logic out of the List, either

```
var filteredTasks: [Task] {
    return tasks.filter { !self.toggleIsOn || !$0.completed.status }
}

...

List(filteredTasks) { task in
    TaskRowView(task)
}
```

or

```
List(tasks.filter( { !self.toggleIsOn || !$0.completed.status })) { task in
    TaskRowView(task)
}
```

Comment: `toggleIsOn` is updated via `@State` with a toggle switch - will this update the list if I use your second approach?

Comment: Also, the reason I went with my approach was because I found that in Apple's tutorials for SwiftUI.

Comment: Yeah the @State will be fine with either approach

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this problem by surrounding the returned value in a `Group` - this meant that the return type was always Group, even if the Group didn't contain anything.

```swift
List(tasks) { task in

    Group {

        if (!self.toggleIsOn) || (!task.completed.status) {

            TaskRowView(task)

        }

    }

}
```